# href link to load page and excute specfic jquery depending on link

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I need a link to go to page and run specific jquery script depending on the link. is this possible?

Heres the menu:

```
       <div class="navDropdown">            
            <ul class="nav ">
                <li><a href="page/index.html#content1">content 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page/index.html#content2">content 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="page/index.html#content3">content 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="page/index.html#content4">content 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

on the page/index.html i have 4 div #content1 & so on with different content in. css of #content is:

> display:none;

And the jquery will change the correct div to which will display the correct selection.

> display:block;

I just cant get my head around this. any help please? :)

Comment: searching google frantically, even if someone could point me to the right direction. Im not sure if this is even possible with jQuery. Im assuming im going to need a listener script on the page/index.html and something on the navigation page to load it into the DOM

Comment: Under document.ready function of index.html , you can use ``location.hash`` to get content1,content2 and so on from the url And based on available value you can show or hide respective div

Comment: @Max In that case, I assume you found some information on the topic. It would be more helpful if you could show that information and how you used it to try to solve your problem along with where you ran into an error.

Comment: thanks @SameerK i´ve been researching about location.hash and think thats the way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use plugin like [jquery.ba-hashchange.js](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/jquery.ba-hashchange.js) if you want something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navDropdown">            
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#content1">content 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content2">content 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content3">content 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content4">content 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content1" style="display: none;">div #content1</div>
<div id="content2" style="display: none;">div #content2</div>
<div id="content3" style="display: none;">div #content3</div>
<div id="content4" style="display: none;">div #content4</div>
```

**jQuery (onload):**

```
$(window).hashchange(function(e){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var id = hash.substring(1, hash.length - 1);
    id = "div[id^='"+id+"']";
    $(id).hide();

    $(hash).show();    
});

$(window).hashchange();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndyont2x/)

Comment: Works great in codepen/fiddle. Just trying to implement something that will work across different pages. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Give it a try and ask me if you need further assistance.

Comment: can confirm this works perfectly, many thanks my internet hero.